# Replace a enterprise JAVA EE enviroment with a lightweight solution

Tags: development-process, java-ee, development-environment

Currently I work in a company with several applications developed in Java, these applications share an "internal framework" with common task like find an employee, check user permissions, etc.

These libs in the internal framework are called through EJB remote, so when setting up a new development environment I need to deploy lots of libs in the developer's machine and I am forced to use a full Java EE container in the development time.

I was thinking in a more lightweight solution like Spring boot, for example. How can I achieve a more easy development setup in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use the functions provided by that interal framework you can't really escape it. Since the internal framwork is built around EJB you probably won't be able to escape the EJB part since the server will only expose his services through EJB.

You may add some things to help the environment setup easier with some scripts and update (or write) a good setup documentation.

There is probably more to say about this but we would need more details and won't fit here, maybe in the chat, or even StackOverflow's chat would fit more i guess.